# XmlNode.InnerText breaks if data is null

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, ssis-2008

I have a script task in VS 2008.  In this script task I get a Data Set and convert it into XML, and loop through the nodes:

```
Dim dsHistory As New DataSet
dsHistory = GetHistoryByYear(Year)


Dim HistoryDoc As New XmlDocument
HistoryDoc.LoadXml(dsHistory.GetXml)


Dim HistoryStudentList As XmlNodeList
Dim StudentNode as XmlNode
HistoryStudentList = HistoryDox.SelectNodes("/NewDataSet/Table")
dsHistory = Nothing


For Each HistoryStudentNode In HistoryStudentList

    Dim dsCurrentAssessment As New DataSet
    dsCurrentAssessment = GetCurrentAssessmentData(...)

    ...code to make sure dataset has data...

    Dim CurrentAssessmentDoc As New XmlDocument
    CurrentAssessmentDoc.LoadXml(dsCurrentAssessment.GetXml)
    Dim CurrentAssessmentNode As XmlNode
    CurrentAssessmentNode = CurrentAssessmentDoc.SelectSingleNode("/NewDataSet")


    For Each CurrentAssessment As XmlNode In CurrentAssessmentNode.SelectNodes("Table")

        InsertAssessmentHistory(HistInstanceID, CurrentAssessment.Item("TITLE").InnerText, CurrentAssessment.Item("CONTENT").InnerText, CurrentAssessment.Item("TYPE").InnerText, CDate(convertAssessmentDate(CurrentAssessment.Item("ADMINISTRATION_DATE").InnerText)), CurrentAssessment.Item("REPORTING_METHOD").InnerText, CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText, CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION").InnerText, CStr(htHistory("ASSESSMENT_ACTION")))

    Next
Next
```

The issue I am having is with the InsertAssessmentHistory method, specifically calling CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText.  The data set is returning null data for one of the records, and it looks like when .InnerText is called on that record it fails with "Object Reference not set to an instance of an object" because the XML tag "...".

Is there a way to call .InnerText, and if there's no data then return null?

Comment: Yes.  Use `?.`  (e.g. `CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS")?.InnerText`)

Comment: @StevenDoggart when I do that intellisense states "Value of type 'System.XML.XMLElement' cannot be converted to String"

Comment: Oh.  Sorry, I failed to notice that this was in 2008 SSIS.  The `?.` operator was added in 2015.  So, if you can't do that, then you'll have to do it more verbosely (e.g. null-coalescing `If`, or a regular `If`/`Else` block, or a ternary `If`/`IIf`, or a custom method that encapsulates it for you).

Comment: `If(CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS") Is Nothing, Nothing, IF(CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText Is Nothing, Nothing, CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText))`

Comment: @DForck42 you have 2 working solutions, why not accepting one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With @codexer's guidance I was able to get it to work.  The inner loop now looks like this:

```
For Each CurrentAssessment As XmlNode In CurrentAssessmentNode.SelectNodes("Table")

    Dim ScoreResults As String
    Dim Interpretation As String


    If CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS") Is Nothing Then
        ScoreResults = Nothing
    Else
        If CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText Is Nothing Then
            ScoreResults = Nothing
        Else
            ScoreResults = CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").InnerText
        End If
    End If


    If CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION") Is Nothing Then
        Interpretation = Nothing
    Else
        If CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION").InnerText Is Nothing Then
            Interpretation = Nothing
        Else
            Interpretation = CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION").InnerText
        End If
    End If



    InsertAssessmentHistory(HistInstanceID, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("TITLE").InnerText, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("CONTENT").InnerText, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("TYPE").InnerText, _
        CDate(convertAssessmentDate(CurrentAssessment.Item("ADMINISTRATION_DATE").InnerText)), _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("REPORTING_METHOD").InnerText, _
        ScoreResults, _
        Interpretation, _
        CStr(htHistory("ASSESSMENT_ACTION")))
Next
```

Comment: Welcome, glad to help. Sorry it looked like a mess, but it was a one line solution, sometimes not the prettiest ...

Comment: @DForck42 you have to accept this answer, even if it yours. so the question is marked as asnwered.

Comment: @Hadi i'm leaving it as-is for a bit to see if someone comes along with a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why converting dataset to xml? why not using dataset without converting it?

Comment: @Hadi unsure, but I think it had to do with it being exported as xml to a flat file. I didn't write this initially, but maintaining it

Answer (score 1):

Why converting to Xml, while you can achieve this using dataset.
This is the dataset version of the inner loop you provided as answer:

```
For Each CurrentAssessment As DataRow In dsCurrentAssessment.Tables(0).Rows

    Dim ScoreResults As String
    Dim Interpretation As String


    If CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS") Is Nothing OrElse _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").ToString) Then
        ScoreResults = Nothing
    Else
        ScoreResults = CurrentAssessment.Item("SCORE_RESULTS").ToString
    End If


    If CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION") Is Nothing OrElse _
        String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION").ToString) Then
        Interpretation = Nothing
    Else
        Interpretation = CurrentAssessment.Item("INTERPRETATION").ToString
    End If


    InsertAssessmentHistory(HistInstanceID, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("TITLE").ToString, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("CONTENT").ToString, _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("TYPE").ToString, _
        CDate(convertAssessmentDate(CurrentAssessment.Item("ADMINISTRATION_DATE").ToString)), _
        CurrentAssessment.Item("REPORTING_METHOD").ToString, _
        ScoreResults, _
        Interpretation, _
        CStr(htHistory("ASSESSMENT_ACTION")))
Next
```